# nginx more_set_headers syntax?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to use more set headers in my nginx config for a CORS header

previously I had

```
add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" *;
```

in my nginx config.
And when I try to change add_header to more_set_headers I get the message `[error] 5265#5265: more_set_headers: wildcard key too short: *`

It works when the it is done like this

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *';
```

But not sure what the difference is and if it would affect nginx behavior.

Any insight helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_headers):

```
more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
```

For multiple headers the syntax is

```
more_set_headers 'Foo: bar' 'Baz: bah';
```